# I have problem with this InDesign script

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

I have Indesign document with 366 qrcdoe and news source
I find this script and edit it to GROUP any qrcode with specific object style (qrcode) and any text with specific paragraph style (مصدر الخبر) individually in entire document

```
var myDoc = app.activeDocument;
// Loop through each page in the document
for (var i = 0; i < myDoc.pages.length; i++) {
  var currentPage = myDoc.pages[i];
  // Find all the page items on the current page that have the object style named "qrcode"
  var qrcodes = currentPage.getElements({objectType: Oval, appliedObjectStyles: "qrcode"});
  // Find all the text frames on the current page that have the paragraph style named "مصدر الخبر"
  var newsSources = currentPage.getElements({objectType: TextFrame, appliedParagraphStyle: "مصدر الخبر"});
  // Loop through each QR code and group it with its associated news sources
  for (var j = 0; j < qrcodes.length; j++) {
    var currentQRCode = qrcodes[j];
    // Find all the news source text frames associated with the current QR code
    var associatedNewsSources = currentQRCode.associatedXMLElements.getElements({objectType: TextFrame, appliedParagraphStyle: "مصدر الخبر"});
    // If there are associated news sources, group them together
    if (associatedNewsSources.length > 0) {
      var currentGroup = currentPage.groups.add([currentQRCode].concat(associatedNewsSources));
      currentGroup.move(currentPage);
    }
  }
  // Loop through each news source text frame and group it with its associated QR codes
  for (var k = 0; k < newsSources.length; k++) {
    var currentNewsSource = newsSources[k];
    // Find all the QR codes associated with the current news source
    var associatedQRCodes = currentNewsSource.getElements({objectType: Oval, associatedXMLElements: "مصدر الخبر"});
    // If there are associated QR codes, group them together
    if (associatedQRCodes.length > 0) {
      var currentGroup = currentPage.groups.add([currentNewsSource].concat(associatedQRCodes));
      currentGroup.move(currentPage);
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

**But when I Run Script I have this Problem**

[image]

**is there any help I well be appreciated**

Comment: Oh my, somebody didnt understand what commenting code means.

Comment: @joojaa 
sorry my English very weak
if you can help me I well be thanks